# Derivative of piecewise function returns one more case

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

I define the following piecewise function:

```
U[c_,n_,g_,p_]:=Piecewise[{{c^(1-g)/(1-g)-n^(1+p)/(1+p),g!=1}, {Log[c]-n^(1+p)/(1+p),g==1}}]
```

When I take the derivative

```
D[U[c,n,g,p],c]
```

It returns a a third unexpected line.

[image]

(In the image, gamma corresponds to g)

What is the meaning of this third line and how can I remove it from the printed output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Instead of using `g != 1` use `g < 1 || g > 1`, then

```
U[c_, n_, g_, p_] := 
 Piecewise[{{c^(1 - g)/(1 - g) - n^(1 + p)/(1 + p), g < 1 || g > 1}}, 
  Log[c] - n^(1 + p)/(1 + p)]

D[U[c, n, g, p], c] // Simplify

(* c^-g *)
```

**EDIT:** Or use `Simplify` with your original definition

```
U[c_, n_, g_, p_] := 
 Piecewise[{{c^(1 - g)/(1 - g) - n^(1 + p)/(1 + p), 
    g != 1}, {Log[c] - n^(1 + p)/(1 + p), g == 1}}]

D[U[c, n, g, p], c] // Simplify

(* c^-g *)
```

Comment: Using Simplify does not return the derivative for the second case of the piecewise function, i.e. I expect two outputs but I only get one

Comment: They simplify to one case since `c^-1 == 1/c`

Comment: I understand thank you

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Mathematica insists on having a default condition (with value zero, unless otherwise specifed).

With

```
ass=D[U[c,n,g,p],c]
```

You can construct something like

```
Piecewise[Drop[ass[[1]]], ass[[1, 2, 1]]]
```

This uses the second terms as the fall through value.